# Removing all GET parameters for redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the following url to homepage using nginx

```
https://www.example.com/old.php?u=BUH09MrRGtnYWB2Nc5CGcX879Y6wqF5EDTij6vphybUekhzY0Qo%3D&b=5
```

The url above should redirect to `https://www.example.com/`

I am using the following rule

```
rewrite ^/old.php(.*)$ https://www.example permanent;
```

The redirect to homepage works but i see the

`https://www.example.com/?u=BUH09MrRGtnYWB2Nc5CGcX879Y6wqF5EDTij6vphybUekhzY0Qo%3D&b=5`

Instead of `https://www.example.com/` in address bar

Answer (score 0):

according to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite , you just need to add a ? at the end of the rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/old.php(.*)$ https://www.example? permanent;
```